# Incorrect Syntax Near inside stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to run a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 Express. But I always get this error:

> Incorrect Syntax Near ')' inside stored procedure

The calling syntax is :

```
Use Demo1
SP_Backup_StoredProcedure '[dbo.FilesStore]', 'F'
```

and the code of the stored procedure is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Backup_StoredProcedure]  
       @dbName sysname, @backupTypeToRun CHAR(1) 
AS 
BEGIN 
       SET NOCOUNT ON; 

       DECLARE @sqlCommand NVARCHAR(1000) 
       DECLARE @dateTime NVARCHAR(20) 

       SELECT @dateTime = REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(),111),'/','-') +'-' +
       REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(),108),':','')  

       DECLARE @databaseFileName NVARCHAR(200)
       SET @databaseFileName = replace(@dbName,']','')
       SET @databaseFileName = replace(@databaseFileName,'[','')

       IF @backupTypeToRun = 'F' 
               SET @sqlCommand = 'BACKUP DATABASE ' + @dbName + 
               ' TO DISK = ''C:\DbBackups\' + @databaseFileName + '_Full_' + @dateTime + '.BAK''' 

       IF @backupTypeToRun = 'D' 
               SET @sqlCommand = 'BACKUP DATABASE ' + @dbName + 
               ' TO DISK = ''C:\DbBackups\' + @databaseFileName + '_Diff_' + @dateTime + '.BAK'' WITH DIFFERENTIAL' 

       IF @backupTypeToRun = 'L' 
               SET @sqlCommand = 'BACKUP LOG ' + @dbName + 
               ' TO DISK = ''C:\DbBackups\' + @databaseFileName + '_Log_' + @dateTime + '.TRN''' 

       EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand 
END
```

Please I tried different answers, I am also using commas for parameters and every available answer. please help

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Thanks for answering, i changed the prefex and still not working. i removed the schema, and still not working. !!

Comment: Did you change your **calling** of the stored procedure to: `EXEC Backup_StoredProcedure N'[FilesStore]', 'F'` ?? A **database** never has a `dbo.` prefix.....

Comment: after changing the table name and restarting the server . The is the message error which i get, "Database 'tbl_test' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many problems with your example.

1. Database name format is `[databasename]`
2. Table name format is `[databasename].[dbo].[tablename]`
3. When calling proc use `EXEC schema.ProcName` or `EXECUTE schema.ProcName`
4. It is best practice to assign parameters explicitly in your case  `EXEC schema.ProcName @dbname = '[dbname]', @backupTypeToRun = 'F'`
5. Like it was already mentioned in comments. `sp_` is reserved for built-in stored procs. Rename it to `usp_` or anything else. When SP starts with `'sp_'` SQL Server will first try to find it in built-in list.
6. Based on your last comment you are trying to pass-in tablename `tbl_test` and not a database name.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
SP_Backup_StoredProcedure '[FilesStore]', 'F'
```

Comment: thanks for answering. i used your code, but still not working. Besides, i don't recognize the difference between your code and mine. But anyway its not working

Comment: As [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191304(v=sql.105).aspx) only database name is used with backup command

Comment: thanks, it works now !!! finally alhamdolelah